# Robotframework IF

Tags: python, if-statement, robotframework

I have a for loop, and inside it an If statement. I can't execute corretly the if statement. Log says, no keyword with =
What could be the problem?

```
:FOR  ${Line}  IN  @{Lines} 
   \  Run keyword If  ${Line_Count} == 1  
   \  ...  ${File}=  BuiltIn.Catenate  SEPARATOR=\n  ${File}  ${Line}
```

Comment: You might want to investigate using [Set Variable If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:FOR  ${Line}  IN  @{Lines} 
\    ${File}=    Run keyword If    '${Line_Count}' == '1'    Catenate  SEPARATOR=\n  ${File}  ${Line}    ELSE    Set Variable    ${File}
```

Explanation - if ${Line Count} != -1, the ${File} will be nullified, as there's no ELSE branch to set it's value. Thus by adding it, and having it return its original value, that case is solved.

*(you can check that behavior in builtin's run_keyword_if() and _split_elif_or_else_branch() sources)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
  :FOR  ${Line}  IN  @{Lines} 
  \    ${File}=    Run keyword If    '${Line_Count}' == '1'    BuiltIn.Catenate  SEPARATOR=\n  ${File}  ${Line}
```

Comment: What is the value of variable '${File}' prior to  FOR loop?

Comment: File will contain strings, I catenate them, and then save into a file. There is a problem because, I have an empty line (because I catenate a "empty string" with the firstline, and the separator is \n. So I want to change the separator before the first string.